# Override permission and authentication classes in ViewSet list method

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to set specific authentication and permission classes on the ListModelMixin of a viewset. I tried the following but it is not working:

```
    def list(self, request):
        self.authentication_classes = (apiauth.SessionAuthentication, )
        self.permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
        return super(TestViewSet, self).list(request)
```

Am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

**@henriquesalvaro's answer does not work for me.**

For some reason `action` is not part of self in `get_authenticators(self)`
So `if self.action == 'list'` does not work for me.

I had to write the following code to get the action.

```
def get_authenticators(self):
        authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]

        action_map = {key.lower(): value for key,
                      value in self.action_map.items()}
        action_name = action_map.get(self.request.method.lower())
        if action_name =="list":
            return [YourPermission]

        return authentication_classes
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if you're looking to override authentication classes for a single action on a viewset. Just tested it out on the most recent version of Django.

Answer (score 1):

When your request reaches the `list` function, it means it has already passed both the authentication and the permission phases.

If you're using the same classes for permission and authentication for all actions on your `ViewSet` you should define them on your class declaration:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    authentication_classes = (apiauth.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

If you're trying to use different authentication/permission classes for the `list` action, you can override the [`get_authenticators`](http://www.cdrf.co/2.4/rest_framework.views/APIView.html#get_authenticators) and [`get_permissions`](http://www.cdrf.co/2.4/rest_framework.views/APIView.html#get_permissions) methods:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    ...

    def get_authenticators(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            # Set up here
            return YourAuthenticators
        return super().get_authenticators()

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            # Set up here
            return YourPermissions
        return super().get_permissions()
```